# Proper use of objects

Tags: java, oop

I have this method `addPerson` (on the main) which is used to set the name of a person.

```
private static Person[] addPerson(Person _person[], int _minAge, int _id){
    int personAge;
    String personName;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What's his age?");
        personAge = scan.nextInt();
        if(personAge >= _minAge){
            if(!_person[_id].getPerson().equals("")){
                System.out.println("Person " + _person[_id].getPerson() + " already exists.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Enter the name of the person");
                Scanner addPerson = new Scanner(System.in);
                personName = addPerson.next();
                _person[_id].setPerson(personName);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Person is not old enough");
        }
    return _person;
}
```

And here is the method `setPerson` in my custom class which is used to set the name of the person.

```
public void setPerson(String name){
    System.out.println("Person added");
    personName = name;
}
```

I know I should be doing the checking on whether that person already exists inside my `setPerson` method, but I am sort of confused with this. As you see I am expecting the user to input an integer, so I guess that I should check that right away to not get an error in case he inputs a string.

So my question is which should be checked within the same method and which on the method on my custom class?

Comment: Your `addPerson` method is very weird. Why an array? Why minimum age as a parameter? Why not have the name as a parameter so you don't need `setPerson`?

Comment: @Gendarme The array is because I need to reference the _id of the _person object `_person[_id]` and the minimum age because I need to check if the age that the user inputs is at least that one. As for `setPerson` I need to use it, so I am just trying to figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: I think that the checking must be in addPerson. And that you should rename your method setPerson to setName in the Person class.

Answer (score 2):

Your code (and your question) is a bit confusing, but from what I can understand you want to know if you should check whether a person exists in the array in `setPerson()` or not?

Well, from what I can gather from your code, you should **not** do it in `setPerson()`, because that's a method in the `Person` class. The `Person` class shouldn't need to know anything about your array of `Person` objects.

So the way you're doing it now is probably your best bet.

**Some general hints about the code:**

There's no need to create a new `Scanner`, you can just use the one you have. So this

```
Scanner addPerson = new Scanner(System.in); 
personName = addPerson.next();
```

becomes this

```
personName = scan.next();
```

I would also suggest you use the name `setName()`instead of `setPerson()`for your method name, it doesn't make sense to have it named one way when what it's actually doing is something else.

Comment: My bad... I messed up copying the code. It's corrected now. It's actually _id as id

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. However I don't have java currently so I didn't test this snippet.

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Main {
    private static final int minAge = 22;
    private static Map<Person> addPerson(Map<Person> people, int id) {
        if(people.containsKey(id)) {
            // print that person with this id exists
            return people;
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        if(age < minAge) {
            // print that given age is invalid
            return people;
        }
        String name = scanner.next();
        people.get(id).setName(name);
        return people;
    }
}
```